# How to make bootbox.prompt work?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I had referred the official documentation on [this](http://bootboxjs.com/), but still I am not able to get it work. I had imported all the necessary css and js files, but still it doesn't seem to work. I am currently testing on Firefox on ubuntu and Chrome on Windows. Is bootbox compatible with all types of browsers? I am using the latest version of bootbox i.e. 4.x

Following is the piece of code:

```js
    $(".alert").click(function(e) {
    bootbox.prompt("Hello world!", function(result) {
    <!-- Some Code -->
    });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootbox/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

 <body>
      
    <p>Content here. <a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a></p>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to turn your post into a code snippet and accidentally fixed your problem.

You should be using `JQuery 1.9.1` or higher as stated by this error. It looks like your issue lies there and not with bootbox itself.

```
"message": "Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4".
```

Updated code below:

```js
    $(".alert").click(function(e) {
    bootbox.prompt("Hello world!", function(result) {
    <!-- Some Code -->
    });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootbox/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

 <body>
      
    <p>Content here. <a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a></p>

 </body>
```